# C# - How i can read last line in txt file

Tags: c#

How i can read last line in txt file and write it to "RichTextBox" ?

**Now i have this:**

```
StreamWriter sw2 = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\Notes\\" + FileTxtBox.Text + "_" + "note" + ".txt");
sw2.WriteLine(NoteTxtBox.Text);
w2.Close();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\Notes\\" + FileTxtBox.Text + "_" + "note" + ".txt");
ShowBOX.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
TextBox.Text = File.ReadLines("filename.txt").Last();
```

`File.ReadLines(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. `.Last()` is a LINQ method that gets the last item from an `IEnumerable` (so in this case, the last line from the file).

Comment: @JD_1609 You can read for example the **third line** with : `File.ReadLines("filename.txt").Take(3).Last();`  or `File.ReadLines("filename.txt").Skip(2).First();`

Answer (score 3):

For realtime last line, launch PowerShell in a process and use `Tail`.

```
void Main()
{
    var fileName = @"C:\BrianTemp\Log.txt";
    var arg = $"Get-Content {fileName} -Wait -Tail 30";
    launchPowershell(arg);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void launchPowershell(string arg)
{
    Process proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "powershell",
            Arguments = arg,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);//TODO: do something with line
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the performance differences of using this method vs the LINQ method?

Comment: I would go for this type of solution for the benefit of continuous output, not performance.  Spinning up a process is no comparison to a LINQ call.  There's no need to look at empirical data to know that much.

Comment: I suppose I just don't really understand what the advantage of that is.

Comment: It depends on the applications needs.  Does the app need discrete data (think Directory.GetFiles) or continuous data (FileSystemWatcher)

Comment: @TJ If you had an application that was pumping out data to a log file, you could use Brian's method to constantly read the (new) contents of this file into your application.